# Curl crashing in function "ossl_connect_common" when multiple network calls are made in parallel

Tags: c++, ios, curl, openssl

**Crashed: Thread**

```
0 libsystem_pthread.dylib
0x5948 pthread_rwlock_rdlock + 110
1 XYZ 0x259ac08 CRYPTO_THREAD_read_lock + 10241200
2 XYZ 0x251a184 int_err_get_item + 9714220
3 XYZ 0x2519f0c ERR_lib_error_string + 9713588
4 XYZ 0x2519cd4 ERR_error_string_n + 9713020
5 XYZ 0x260bbfc ossl_strerror + 10704036
6 XYZ 0x260c4e4 ossl_connect_common + 10706316
7 XYZ 0x2610538 Curl_ssl_connect_nonblocking + 10722784
8 XYZ 0x25e2df8 https_connecting + 10536608
9 XYZ 0x25e2d90 Curl_http_connect + 10536504
10 XYZ 0x25f0990 multi_runsingle + 10592824
11 XYZ 0x25f049c curl_multi_perform + 10591556
12 XYZ 0x25d8d28 curl_easy_perform + 10495440
```

****Operating Version : IOS 15
Curl Version : 7.76.1
OpenSSL Version : OpenSSL 1.1.1k 25 Mar 2021.**

**Issue :** We are making multiple network calls(get/post/multipart)in multiple threads and it works but after some times it crashes when device goes into background.

Comment: Build and run your program with ThreadSanitizer.

Comment: Show code. Are you sharing the same curl context between threads? Also the ERR_error_string_n  is documented to be not thread-safe.

Comment: No we are not sharing the same context between threads. We have separate objects for each threads.